# Erro na hora de criar uma trigger

Tags: mysql

estou criando essa trigger

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE TRIGGER reposta3A   
AFTER INSERT ON utilizacao_veiculo
FOR EACH ROW    
BEGIN           
SELECT emite_mensagem();
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

mas quando executo o comando show triggers;
ela não aparece como se estivesse criada

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seu problema seja com a criação da trigger, tente executar essa query para criar a trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE

    TRIGGER `reposta3A` AFTER INSERT ON `utilizacao_veiculo` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        SELECT emite_mensagem();
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: ainda continua não mostrando como um trigger criada

Comment: da algum erro quando você executa esta query que te passei?

Comment: não tem erro nenhum, simplesmente não cria a trigger